# DISTINCT on Two Individual Columns instead of Group of Two Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, cockroachdb

Table: `Campaign_mapping`

| campaign_id | emailid_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 6 |

Table: `Leads`

| id | campaign_id | emailid_id | data_a | data_b | data_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |  | a | b | c |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | a1 | b2 | c3 |
| 4 | 3 |  | a2 | b3 | c4 |
| 5 | 4 |  | a5 | b5 | c2 |
| 6 | 5 |  | a1 | b | c |
| 7 | 6 |  | a | b2 | c |
| 8 | 2 |  | a3 | b | c4 |
| 9 | 1 | 3 | a | b2 | c4 |
| 10 | 1 |  | a | b1 | c |
| 11 | 2 |  | a2 | b | c |
| 12 | 3 |  | a | b | c4 |
| 13 | 4 |  | a | b2 | c |
| 14 | 5 |  | a1 | b | c |

Trial query:

```
SELECT 
    Campaign_mapping.*, 
    Leads.* 
FROM 
    Campaign_mapping 
JOIN 
    Leads ON Campaign_mapping.campaign_id = Leads.campaign_id 
WHERE 
    (Campaign_mapping.emailid_id = Leads.emailid_id 
     OR Leads.emailid_id IS NULL) 
    AND Leads.id = (SELECT tblA.id FROM Leads tblA 
                    WHERE Campaign_mapping.campaign_id = tblA.campaign_id 
                    LIMIT 1);
```

Current output:

| campaign_id | emailid_id | id | campaign_id | emailid_id | data_a | data_b | data_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  | a | b | c |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |  | a | b | c |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |  | a | b | c |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | a1 | b2 | c3 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 |  | a5 | b5 | c2 |
| 5 | 4 | 6 | 5 |  | a1 | b | c |
| 6 | 5 | 7 | 6 |  | a | b2 | c |

One possible Solution (needs better output or randomization for max rows) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (campaign_mapping.emailid_id) * FROM campaign_mapping JOIN Leads ON campaign_mapping.campaign_id = Leads.campaign_id WHERE (campaign_mapping.emailid_id = Leads.emailid_id OR Leads.emailid_id is NULL)
```

Output (Needs better):

| campaign_id | emailid_id | id | campaign_id | emailid_id | data_a | data_b | data_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | NULL | a | b | c |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | NULL | a5 | b5 | c2 |
| 6 | 5 | 7 | 6 | NULL | a | b2 | c |

Final expected output should be:

| campaign_id | emailid_id | id | campaign_id | emailid_id | data_a | data_b | data_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  | a | b | c |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 1 |  | a | b1 | c |
| 1 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 3 | a | b2 | c4 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 |  | a5 | b5 | c2 |
| 6 | 5 | 7 | 6 |  | a | b2 | c |

In a nutshell, I need unique `emailid_id` and unique `Leads.id` along with other rows value.
So, c.emailid_id should be unique among all rows, and same goes with Leads.id .

**Please note:** `Campaign_mapping` is not exactly a table, but rather a complex join with filters that finally gives this output, as shown in table.

Here are the SQL queries for anyone who would love to help me resolve it:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign_mapping (
    campaign_id int,
    emailid_id int
);

INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (1 , 1);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (1 , 2);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (1 , 3);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (2 , 2);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (4 , 4);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (5 , 4);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (6 , 5);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (7 , 7);
INSERT INTO campaign_mapping VALUES (8 , 6);



CREATE TABLE leads (
    id int,
    campaign_id int,
    emailid_id int,
    data_a text,
    data_b text,
    data_c text
);
    
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (2 , 1, null, 'a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (3 , 2, 2, 'a1', 'b2', 'c3' );
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (4 , 3, null, 'a2', 'b3', 'c4');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (5 , 4, null, 'a5', 'b5', 'c2');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (6 , 5, null, 'a1', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (7 , 6, null, 'a', 'b2', 'c');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (8 , 2, null, 'a3', 'b', 'c4');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (9 , 1, 3, 'a', 'b2', 'c4');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (10 , 1, null, 'a', 'b1', 'c');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (11 , 2, null, 'a2', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (12 , 3, null, 'a', 'b', 'c4');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (13 , 4, null, 'a', 'b2', 'c');
INSERT INTO leads VALUES (14 , 5, null, 'a1', 'b', 'c');
```

I would prefer a join solution, as the number of rows in Campaign_mapping can go beyond 2000, but Where IN and minor processing at application layer with two seperate queries is acceptable as well.

Comment: Null is an acceptable value, and it's demo content and type, I just used to create scenario tables.

Comment: @Dai -- your comment on text may be DBMS dependent.  I read somewhere that on PostgreSQL the text datatype is every bit as efficient as varchar(x).

Comment: @marc_s thanks for fixing the formatting. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Hambone I jumped to the assumption that the OP is using SQL Server.

Comment: Why does `1, 1, 2, 1` win over either `1, 2, 2, 1` or `1, 3, 2, 1` ? Is a specific ordering necessary to determine which records from the first result set "Win" over other other record combinations? Can you explain more about what logic you, as a human, are using to get to that desired result?

Comment: @JNevill no ordering. Either can be choosen. I don't really care which version comes out, just it should be DISTINCT(emailid_id) and DISTINCT(Leads.id) with maximum rows present.

Comment: @Dai tagged it with Postgres and Cockroach. Just to avoid a DB specific functions that I might not be able to use. :)

Comment: Can this be solved with `SELECT c.campaign_id, max(c.emailid_id), l.id, max(l.campaign_id), max(l.emailid_id), max(data_a), max(data_b), max(data_b) FROM campaign_mapping c JOIN leadsl ON c.campaign_id = l.campaign_id GROUP BY c.campaign_id, l.id;`? Or is it important that the record returned be made by only a single record in the group-by set, but you don't care which one?

Comment: @JNevill two issues with that, values from using max on individual columns might not result the exact row, but could potentially return value of different rows combined. And second it gives duplication for c.emailid_id . Did a quick try on https://pike.link/online-sql-compiler

Comment: You mean you get two rows for the same emailid_id? This is how we understand the task. One result row per emailid_id / Leads.id combination. Is this not what you want? Must there be no two rows for the same emailid_id and no two rows for the same Leads.id? In that case, with six rows (emailid_id / Leads.id) = 1/2, 1/3, 2/2, 2/3, 3/2, 4/3 what to return?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner required output would be either '1/2, 2/3',  or '1/3, 2/2' or '2/2, 4/3', and so on. Basically c.emailid_id should be unique among all rows, and same goes with Leads.id . Think it like this, you cannot send emails to same lead from two emailids, and neither you can send to two leads, from one email id at the same time.

Comment: Okay, so you just dismiss emails and/or leads. There are Leads IDs you would not show in the results. How many are we allowed to suppress? Would an empty query result (no rows) be okay? That would comply with the rules "no duplicate emails" and "no duplicate leads". It seems you must be very explicit on the rules how to pick rows. You may end up with some recursive query combining all possible email/lead combinations and pick one of those that produce the maximum number of result rows.

Comment: Oh, but wait, you have tagged two DBMS in order to get a query that works in your DBMS the name of which you don't want to tell us? DBMS differ a lot in what they feature and in their standard compliancy. Are recursive querries even allowed? And lateral joins? ...

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if an empty result set happens once in blue moon that's acceptable to. As this will be a batch job running every few minutes processing batches. So, till average resulting value has covered maximum of unique (c.emailids) it works. Cockroach supports almost everything postgres does including lateral and correlated. Tagged both, as most people are much more familiar with Postgres.

Comment: Yep, that maximum of unique emails thing is what I thought. This is an iterative process, and at least in SQL it is recursive. Pick a row, try to find another without producing duplicates, try to find yet another, etc. Then start with another combination. Thus find all possible output rows that match the requirements. Then check which combinations led to the maximum number of result rows. Pick one of these and show the results. Quite a task. You can try that in SQL or in a programming language if you prefer that. It will take rather long, both to write it and to run it. Good luck.

Comment: The goal here is still confusing after reading all the comments above, tbh. could you explain the business logic here you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I was able to achieve one possible set of result. Any ideas on throwing in randomization there for avg case better output (more number of rows)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to resolve this using.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (campaign_mapping.emailid_id) campaign_mapping.*, leads.* FROM campaign_mapping JOIN Leads ON campaign_mapping.campaign_id = Leads.campaign_id WHERE (campaign_mapping.emailid_id = Leads.emailid_id OR Leads.emailid_id is NULL) ORDER BY campaign_mapping.emailid_id, RANDOM()) ORDER BY id, RANDOM();
```

If anyone got a better optimized one (giving max possible rows, or randomization with max possible rows) without random() performance hit, you will have my deepest gratitude.

Note: **DISTINCT ON ()** is a postgres construct and supported on cockroachDB, which might not work on other sql solutions.